# I want to find a specfic group and get their email addresses

Tags: email, groups

I need to know how to request a specific group (Fundraisers) using their email address.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I'm not entirely clear what you are asking. If the answers below don't help, perhaps you could edit the question to clarify and if possible provide a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE! Unless I have misunderstood this is straight forward, this is very simple. If you got to **Find Contact** you can select the the contacts in the particular group (third box down) and that listing will include email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Mick, you can find contacts in a group, this will list contacts and than you can export the records into csv with emails fields.

Another approach would be to use Contact Summary report to fetch contacts from a group and export them into csv or pdf